# How can I reenable the warning about unsupported Python version by VS Code debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, windows-10

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.78.0 and version v2023.8.0 of the Python extension on Windows 10. When I tried to debug an old project requiring Python 2.7.13 (provided by a virtual environment), I got a warning saying *The debugger in the python extension no longer supports python version minor than 3.7*. I selected *Do not show again* in the dialog and switched to an older version of the extension.

Now I would like that dialog to show again, but can't find a setting to do that. How can I reenable the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general settings in vscode exist in the user or workspace ***settings.json***, and there is also a database file ***state.vscdb*** in vscode.

The `settings.json` file stores information about user settings, such as preferences and keybindings. This file is a plain text JSON file that can be opened and edited by clicking the Settings icon in the left sidebar.

The `state.vscdb` file is an SQLite database file that contains metadata and state information for all files that VSCode has open in the workspace, such as file path, encoding, and open/closed status.

When `Do not show again` is clicked, neither the user nor the workspace ***settings.json*** changes, since such settings are stored in ***state.vscdb***.

[image]

#### solution

1. You can install [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) to open the `state.vscdb` file (*On my machine it exists at the following path*).

   ```
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
   ```

   *Before editing the `state.vscdb` file, you need to close vscode first.*
2. Open the `state.vscdb` file in **SQLiteStudio** and select the `Data` tab on the right

   [image]
3. Scroll down to find the record whose key is `ms-python.python`

   --> Double-click its value

   --> Select the `Text` tab in the pop-up panel

   --> scroll to the end

   --> remove the last `,"doNotShowPython36DebugDeprecatedAgain":true`

   --> click `OK`

   [image]
4. Click `commit` to submit changes

   [image]

   *After submitting, you can click the blue refresh button and check whether the `ms-python.python` value has changed.*
5. Open vscode at this time, and the prompt box will pop up again when using *python 2.7.13* to debug the script.

***Special Note: Please make sure that vscode is closed when performing the above operations.***

Comment: Wow, great answer. I found the database at `%appdata%\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb` and selected the record to edit with `select * from ItemTable where key = 'ms-python.python'`. After the change, the warning is back.