# Clicked on "always continue build" by accident and now i don't get the "build failed" message anymore

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, vscode-extensions

I was running my code and build failed because of a mistake. By accident i clicked on always continue. Now i never see "build failed" again and the code runs despite the errors.
My code had a part to take input from the user and perform a method on it. Now it takes the input although there is an error in the method and then shows error in the terminal after entering all inputs.

How can i get the "buil failed" to appear again?? Please help!

I tried resetting setting and uninstalling. NOTHING WORKED!

Comment: You can try the steps given in this answer to properly remove vscode settings and get a fresh starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462074

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Such settings are generally stored in the ***state.vscdb*** database file, for me it was here(*C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage*).

You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206135/19133920) to modify it.